# SQLite Inner Join with Limit on Left Table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, inner-join

Firstly, let me describe a scenario similar to the one I am facing; to better explain my issue. In this scenario, I am creating a system which needs to select 'n' random blog posts from a table and then get all the replies for those selected posts.

Imagine my structure like so:

```
blog_posts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, thepost TEXT)  
blog_replies(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, postid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES blog_posts(id), thereply TEXT)
```

This is the current SQL I have, but am getting an error:

```sql
SELECT blog_post.id, blog_post.thepost, blog_replies.id, blog_replies.thereply 
FROM (SELECT blog_post.id, blog_post.thepost FROM blog_post ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT ?)  
INNER JOIN blog_replies
ON blog_post.id=blog_replies_options.postid;
```

Here is the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: hmquestion.id
```

Comment: The error you are getting is because you aren't selecting anything from that table.  You moved the logic to your subquery.  Try adding an alias to your subquery of `hmquestion` -- `select ... from (...) hmquestion inner ...`

Comment: Your text mentions three tables that I do not see in the SQL.  Can you fix the question so the text and the SQL are about the same topic?

Comment: @sgeddes, would you be able to expand on what you're saying. I'm fairly new to SQL and am not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hmm? There are only two tables mentioned?

Comment: Still . . . `blog_posts` is not `hmquestion` and so on.  (The text wraps on my screen so it looked like three tables).

Comment: Apologies. That was an error when I was creating the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query needs an alias added to the subquery.  This will allow you to reference the fields from your subquery within the outer query:

```
SELECT hmquestion.id, hmquestion.question,
   hmquestion_options.id, hmquestion_options.option  
FROM (SELECT hmquestion.id, hmquestion.question 
      FROM hmquestion ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT ?) AS hmquestion <--Add Alias Here
   INNER JOIN hmquestion_options
      ON hmquestion.id=hmquestion_options.questionid;
```

As is, you're outer query doesn't know what `hmquestion` references.

Comment: Your method has seemed to fix my problem. Thank you :)